# Piping to a command with flags

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

I know this must have been asked before, I wasn't sure what to search for exactly, so please excuse the duplicate question.

How does one 'pull in' a variable into the right spot when piped in from a previous command?  I'm trying to find a PID, then find open files related to that PID, then narrow it down to one file, then execute a command on that file.  Here's the command:

`ps x | grep IINA | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`

Ok, that gives me a PID, great.  Now I want to `lsof -p` that PID, but I can't simply do `ps x | grep IINA | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | lsof -p`.

Without doing `ps x | grep IINA | grep -v grep | lsof -p 'awk '{print $1}''` (again, excuse the incorrect backticks), how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lsof` utility expects the PID on the command line, not on its standard input.

You may use

```
lsof -p "$( pgrep IINA )"
```

This will execute `pgrep` with `IINA` as its argument, and the output of that will be handed to `lsof` as an option argument to the `-p` option using a command substitution.

If `IINA` is not the name of the command, but a part of the command line used to start the process, add the `-f` flag to `pgrep`.

If you get multiple hits with `pgrep` you may want to use `-n` (gets the most recently started matching process) or `-o` (gets the oldest matching process), if your `pgrep` implementation supports this, or you may use

```
lsof -p "$( pgrep IINA | tr '\n' ',' )"
```

to create a comma-delimited list of PIDs for `lsof -p`.